# IE9 input type file get binary data

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I need to get the binary data from input type file using JavaScript. In IE10+ there is no problem because of `FileReader`, but in IE9 I do not know how to figure out. I saw some post that recomends to use Flash or ActiveX but ActiveX will require extra changes in security settings in IE and Flash to install Shockwave. Is there no any other options? Really?

Comment: The best solution for this is to let the client know that their browser does not support all the features you use so they either upgrade or migrate browsers. Even _Windows Vista_ users should be starting to get nudged here because the end of extended support for Vista is now just 2 years away on _April 11, 2017_

Comment: I'd imagine most IE9 users will have Flash installed, given it's only newer browsers that supplant its functionality. What's the mention of Shockwave though? I would have thought this could be done with just Flash (Flash != Shockwave)

Answer (score 4):

> It is not exists any other options ? Really ?

Really (not client-side). That's ***why*** we have the File API (which is implemented in IE10+).

Well, okay, you could use a Java applet, but they have the same sorts of issues as ActiveX and Flash (and won't be supported in Chrome much longer [already aren't on *nix]).

To support IE9 you'll basically have to post the file to a server and handle processing it there.

Comment: now I know how to tally lots of rep-points here.  thanks for the tutorial.  As an alternative approach.  Maybe if we have access to the server, we can request the file in base64 text.

Comment: @user4749485: Why would you want base64 text? And rep is irrelevant. Being helpful is relevant, not rep.

Comment: @TJ   it easily converts back to binary.   ("no-can-do" is a 5+ helpful?)

Comment: @user4749485: It does, but I'm not seeing any point. If you're sending the file to the server (which for IE9 would have to be a post with an `input type=file`), base64 is irrelevant.

Comment: @user4749485: The question is "is there reall no other way?" and the answer is "No." Yes, that's helpful. And FYI, total likely rep gain for me on this is likely to be in the 0-15 points range, as I'll have hit the daily rep cap anyway and so only an accept will really do anything. Not, again, that it matters.

Comment: @TJ  -  put the base64 file on the server, and ship it as text/plain.  then client-side, request that text/plain file and convert the base64 to binary.

Comment: @user4749485: There's no need to do that, the browser will do it for you. I'm assuming the OP doesn't need to send it back to the browser after it's uploaded, but even if they did, base64 is unnecessary -- just do an ajax request for the file data and return it as `application/octet-stream`, then read it off the XHR `responseText` as bytes. No need for base64, which would dramatically inflate the data size on the wire.

Answer (score 1):

If it's your server, you could put a base64 formatted file on it, and send it as text/plain.  Then request that client-side, and easily convert it to binary.
Here's a ready-made demo, from some IE8 issue of the past.
It is xhr'ing "smiley.dataURL.txt".
https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XS0o2V0JQSkRFM2s/xhr-onload-test.html?dataURL

Comment: forcing application/octet-stream then reading responseText won't work.  [screenshot](https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XS0o2V0JQSkRFM2s/that-dont-work.png)